# I can not use livedata on databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, mutablelivedata

I'm trying to reach my value as livedata in xml but I getting this error **"   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method"** and **"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference"**

> Xml file

```
<data>
     <variable
        name="detailViewModel"
        type="com.kseyko.satellite.ui.view.detail.DetailViewModel" />
</data>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.view.detail.DetailFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDetailFirstFlight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
```

android:text="@{detailViewModel.formatDate(detailViewModel.satelliteLiveData.first_flight)}" />

> viewHolder

class DetailViewModel(private val satelliteRepository: SatelliteRepository) : BaseViewModel() {

```
private val _satelliteLiveData = MutableLiveData<Satellite>()
var satelliteLiveData: LiveData<Satellite> = _satelliteLiveData

fun fetchSatellite(satellitePosition: Int) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val satelliteLive = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            satelliteRepository.getSatellite(satellitePosition)
        }
        _satelliteLiveData.value = satelliteLive
    }
}

fun formatDate(firstFlight: String?): String {
    var formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val date = formatter.parse(firstFlight)
    formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
    return formatter.format(date)
}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: Your live data initially contains null value that's why you are getting this error. See if you can provide a default `Satellite` to the `satelliteLiveData` like `private val _satelliteLiveData = MutableLiveData(Satellite())`

Answer (score 0):

Where did you call the `fetchSatellite` method? Null Pointer Exceptions means that you have not set the data for `_satelliteLiveData` yet. Create `init { }` block then put `_satelliteLiveData` inside to fetch data